# Is there a way to print values in gRPC Context into logs using logback?

Tags: logback, grpc, grpc-java

I am writing a new micro service using gRPC. Traditionally, when logging I used to populate the trace Id in MDC of logback and the logback configuration directly takes care of printing the trace id in all the log statements. With gRPC I am making use of Context for setting the trace id, but couldn't figure out a way to directly log them using the logback config file.

I have figured that Context is the right place to do this from this link [How to intercept the headers from in call to one service and insert it to another request in gRPC-java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145878/how-to-intercept-the-headers-from-in-call-to-one-service-and-insert-it-to-anothe)

Find below the pattern that I use to print values from MDC of logback in java projects.

```
<Pattern>%date{dd-MM-yyyy;HH:mm:ss.SSS}|[%mdc{CLIENT-ID}]|[%mdc{REQ-ID}]|[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
```

Is there a way to print the values from the Context into log statements directly like above? Is this even the right way to think about logging trace id in the logs when dealing with gRPC

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track by using the context.  The way to do it is to write a custom layout (subclass `LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent>`) that will query the context and write it in the log.  The code to query the context is:

```
Span span = ContextUtils.getValue(Context.current());
```

then to convert it to a string:

```
span.getContext().getTraceId().toLowerBase16()
```