# gRPC handling metadata (headers) end-to-end

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I have service (gRPC) which I define by protobuf and the service has one method to call.
I want to call the method and pass a header (as we usually do with rest) using clientStub of gRPC service but I couldn't find how to usually to do in gRPC. I decided to do it via **ClientInterceptor** and put my ClientInterceptor to ClientStub.

```
public class ClientHeadersInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientHeadersInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT> interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method, CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
        return new ForwardingClientCall.SimpleForwardingClientCall<ReqT, RespT>(next.newCall(method, callOptions)) {
            @Override
            public void start(Listener<RespT> responseListener, Metadata headers) {
                headers.put("test", "test");
                headers.put("test1", "test");
                super.start(new ForwardingClientCallListener.SimpleForwardingClientCallListener<RespT>(responseListener) {
                    @Override
                    public void onHeaders(Metadata headers) {
                        LOGGER.info("header received from server:" + headers);
                    }
                }, headers);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So I need these values of headers in my business logic. I mean how to get these values in **impl** Service of gRPC?

I solved this by creating **ServerInterceptor** which gets all values of metadata and put in Context.

```
@GRpcGlobalInterceptor
public class ServeInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> serverCall,
                                                                 Metadata metadata,
                                                                 ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> serverCallHandler) {
        Context current = Context.current();
        current = Context.current()
                    .withValue("test", metadata.get("test"))
                    .withValue("test1", metadata.get("test1"));


        return Contexts.interceptCall(current, serverCall, metadata, serverCallHandler);
    }


}
```

Then, finally, when I put everything in Context I use the context wherever I need to get these values.

```
String testValue = Context.key("test").get();
String test1Value = Context.key("test1").get();
```

**So is it really the only way to get in your service metadata (headers) from a client?**

Comment: Metadata is for wire-level propagation. Context is for in-process propagation. Generally the application should not need to interact directly with Metadata (in Java) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47147109/379906

Comment: Anyway, I can't understand what is the best practice to do it? Your message I got that I have to handle metadata only in ServerInterceptor, okay. So what's next? What if I need these values in my Service exactly? Should I reput all metadata in Context and pass it via Contexts.interceptCall() ?

Comment: Maybe there is a rule like "If you need some values in Service, don't put it metadata pass via proto message" ?